# Why does the bool value change twice with one input in python?

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean

If you enter e while inside the while loop, I want the switch to be False and stay false. When you enter e again for a second separate time in the while loop, I want it to be true and stay true. However, it just switches it to false for one moment then it switches back to true then stays true. What am I doing wrong?

```
switch = True
x = 1 
if x == 1: 
  while x == 1: 
    command = input('')   
    if command == 'e':
        switch = False
        print(switch)
    if not switch:
        if command == 'e':
            switch = True
            print(switch)
```

Comment: The code does exactly what you told it to do, which isn't the same as what you describe in words. To understand this, you can add `print()` statements in your code to follow its execution and see the values of the variables.

Comment: Check what order things happen in - it can be a good exercise to step through your code manually, one line at a time

Comment: For more tips on debugging your code, read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want `switch` to toggle back and forth, the shortest way is something like this:

```
switch = True
while True:
    print(switch)
    command = input()
    if command == 'e':
        switch = not switch
```